# Windows batch file > appears to modify input to java command in the .bat file

Tags: java, windows, batch-file

I have a Windows .bat file which contains a java call.  The java call looks something like this:

```
java -Dfile.encoding=Cp437 -jar name.jar -p "path\filename.prop"
```

The filename.prop file contains several parameters used by the java program.
I am running this .bat file directly from the command window.

The .bat file works fine as long as I allow it to output the log to the command window.  However, if I add redirection of the log, it causes errors indicating that it is NOT looking for the file defined in the -p parameter as it should be.

So:

`myfile.bat`   - works, but writes log information to the command window

`myfile.bat > filename.log`   - stops immediately with errors written to command window.

`myfile.bat > filename.log 2>&1`  - stops immediately with errors written to the log file.

The error produced is this:

java.io.FileNotFoundException: path\filename.prop (The system cannot find the path specified)

where path\filename.prop is NOT the value of the -p parameter in the .bat file.  (Note: I did not write the java program which is being called.  I suspect that the value of path\filename.prop that I am seeing in the error is possibly one that is hardcoded in the program from testing times, but I am not certain.)

How can redirecting the log output have an effect on the parameters read by the java call inside the .bat file?  Is it somehow preventing the java call from "seeing" the -p parameter? What am I missing?

What do I need to change to allow the java call to use the -p parameter in the .bat file?

Comment: Strange; what happens if you try `myfile.bat > con`?

Comment: Does `path\filename.prop` contain non ASCII characters, i.e. characters not listed in upper table of [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/)?

Comment: > con is the default action, and the -p parameter is correctly read, just as it is when I leave > con off, but of course, I don't get to capture the log.

Comment: There are no extended ASCII characters involved.

Comment: it appears that the -p parameter is getting lost when the log messages are sent to a file.  It does not show up in the log or error files, but it is not available to the java program either.  I have tried playing around with various input routing options, but so far have not succeeded in passing the parameter to the java program while capturing the log.